# Very unusual kitchen tools

Tags: equipment, utensils

I found this very interesting [post](http://forum.xcitefun.net/unseen-and-amazing-old-kitchen-utensils-t69232.html). I can guess what some of them must be but have no idea about the others. Can someone please help identify these:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. [image]
6. [image]
7. [image]
8. [image]
9. [image]
10. [image]
11. [image]
12. [image]
13. [image]
14. [image]

Comment: There's only one I can ID with 100% certainty. #9 is a pair of butter churns. Pour milk in jar, crank paddles, get butter.

Comment: It would be helpful to number these for easier responses.

Comment: If only this site allowed other users to edit posts... :) I've done it

Comment: These are some fascinating, weird tools, but this looks a bit OT because it's not about a specific problem.  I'm presuming that you don't have most of these things sitting around collecting dust because you don't know how to use them.

Comment: Number 7 looks like sugar cube scissors, used to pick up and serve sugar cubes. And 11 looks like tweezers to remove fish bones, such as from salmon. Interesting array of tools.

Comment: I can confirm 7 for sugar cube scisors. I have a pair handed down the family for a couple generations.

Comment: If this question is going to stick around, I think there should be  a single community-wiki answer. It's kind of a mess trying to read through the answers and match things up with the photos, and parse out conflicting dupes and agreeing dupes, and figure out which items haven't yet been identified.

Comment: okay, I *tried* to fix the numbering, but the preview when editing and what it's displaying when *not* editing *do not* match up.

Comment: Okay, numbering is a little better, and I've created the community wiki answer. I'll go through and delete the existing answers now.

Comment: Just a question of how to use google translate on an exiting web site (the russian one antonH links http://stalic-kitchen.livejournal.com/666290.html)

Comment: Hi, whoever marked it as being too broad, it is an identification of some unusual kitchen tools and is food history as well. So, I don't understand why it should be categorised as being too broad.

Comment: @Divi Yes, kitchen tools and food history are on topic. But "too broad" doesn't have anything to do with whether the subject is on or off topic. It's possible to ask a question that's too broad about anything. I imagine someone thought it was too broad because you asked about 14 different tools, rather than something more specific.

Comment: @Jefromi: I can create 14 different questions to be very very specific but I still don't see the problem. They are very specific things I asked about and there are no guidelines saying how many items I can ask to be identified in one question

Comment: @Divi I did not say I agreed. I attempted to explain why someone might have voted how they did, and in particular why your argument (it's about tools and history) has nothing to do with it. It's clear that asking about one thing is okay, and asking about 1000 is not, and somewhere in between is a line. If I had thought this was clearly too broad, I would have voted as such, and your question would be closed. But I personally think this is on the okay side of the line, though it's definitely pushing it.

Comment: @Jefromi: Thanks for the explanation. Sorry, I didn't mean to sound angry :)

Comment: Back when "too localised" existed as a close reason, this would have been a definite candidate for closure on the grounds that someone else who is trying to identify one of these tools wouldn't be able to find this question with a search engine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a collection of identifications from existing answers. If you know what something is, please add it here, rather than adding yet another answer - and remember to explain how you use it!

1. **An egg scissor**. Lee Valley used to sell some as recently as this century. You hold it like scissors, open the blades, put the circle over the top of your hard-boiled egg (which is sitting upright in an egg cup) and close the blades, neatly cutting off the top of the egg. The chicken motif reinforces the purpose. It's gold coloured because it's an entirely showing off tool that nobody genuinely needs.

[image: image 1]

2. Fork for sardines

[image: image 2]

3. **A pair of tongs for asparagus.** Thumb goes in the top ring, two fingers in the rings underneath. Just for asparagus. Yes, it's silly.

[image: image 3]

4. **A butter or cheese knife with an integrated fork.** Cut a pat of butter, use the fork to transfer it wherever it's going.

[image: image 4]

5. Knife for oranges

[image: image 5]

6. **Another butter/cheese knife+fork.**

[image: image 6]

7. **Sugar cube scissors.** Used to pick up and serve sugar cubes.

[image: image 7]

8. **A cherry pitter.** Insert cherry, work the action, no more cherry pit.

[image: image 8]

9. **A pair of butter churns.** Pour cream in jar, crank paddles, get butter. You can move the top from jar to jar.

[image: image 9]

10. **A bbq-type fork.** It has a little piece of machinery integrated to push whatever it is you've skewered off again. If you squeeze the little handles sticking out at the top, the scissor action will push the end down. I guess it removes the need to use another utensil to do the job...? (It's either that or something designed for easy fire-roasting while you sit at a comfortable distance.)

[image: image 10]

11. **A strawberry stem remover.** They still sell these: http://www.shop.thekozynook.com/Strawberry-Huller-5582.htm  ***OR*** **Tweezers to remove fish bones, such as from salmon.** ***OR*** Tweezers to pluck feathers from birds.

[image: image 11]

12. Stand for fruit knives

[image: image 12]

13. **A sugar spoon with integrated caster.** Take a bit of sugar from the bowl, then use the hole to drizzle it over your food.

[image: image 13]

14. Device for holding game at cutting (put it on one of the critter's legs, lock it with the screw)

[image: image 14]

Comment: They appear [here in Russian](http://stalic-kitchen.livejournal.com/666290.html), so I used Google Translate.

Comment: Nice link - there's even more neat stuff there.  Also, Google Translate yields something akin to dadaist poetry.  To wit: "Two cups with shelf mustache. Surely these were Hercule Poirot. Horn as shoes for infant feeding. Somewhere in the East still runs like horns."